# Windows 8 BSOD at startup ; no crash dump available?

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I have a strange problem with my computer. I have upgraded from win7 to win8. All was working fine the first day but now I can't even boot windows : I get a BSOD each time.
The computer has been running perfectly fine on win7 for 2 years and I can't understand what is happenning.

I have boot an ubuntu version from the same computer (separated disk with a linux version for emergencies :) at least it was useful this time) and tried to explore the disk.

But :

- The C:/minidump folder is empty
- There is no C:/Minidumps folder
- There is no C:/Windows/MEMORY.dmp

I was thinking that windows 8 could at least give us some information. My computer is totally unusable and I haven't a single clue to solve that.Are there other places where I could find more information about this issue ?$

EDIT : I was finally able to get a part of the stop code : it ends with "BOOT_DEV"

Thanks,

Comment: Boot to safe mode, check the system event log. There might be something in there, unless it was just completely unable to write to the disk at all.

Comment: Actually it seems to be able to write on the disk (based on modification dates for the system32/config folder)

Comment: Windows needs a pagefile to create dumps. Have you disabled the pagefile?

Comment: I may have indeed changed some parameters in Win7 due to the fact that the system was running on a SSD disk. Win8 may have kept the parameters (when possible). Is there a way to change that ? (I am always thinking in a linux way but maybe is there some conf file somewhere ?)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how else can I troubleshoot this issue?

If so, I would use your Ubuntu Recovery CD and copy the event logs from the C:\windows\system32\config folder to another working Windows PC. You can open them from event viewer on the machine simply by selecting "Action" and then "Open Saved Log" and then navigating to the saved logs.

Another option to find more information about this issue would to turn on the "Disable Automatic restart on system failure" option. This will stop the BSOD from rebooting and should allow you to write down the error code. This option is on the same screen where you enter into safe mode. It's a little harder to get to in Windows 8 but it's detailed [in the article nicely](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/). (Just select "Disable Automatic Restart on system failure" instead of booting into safe mode)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had forgotten the system32/config folder. I will try to check the file manually though since I don't have any windows working here.

Answer (score -1):

The dumps are in `C:\Windows\minidumps`, not in `C:\minidumps`. ;)